# How to Website URL Shareable to LinkedIn on wordpress website. how we can show image on there

Tags: wordpress

how to show image on linkedin when i'll share website URL on linked in.when i posted url on linkedin but image is not showing. how can we solve that issues.

Comment: You need to add opengraph tags to your head section of html. One of the tags will contain image that should be fetched by linkedin as an image associated with this page.

Comment: Hi Nick.....thank you but i have one question it's a wordpress website. where i'll put that html code on wordpress website. which page i'll put that code. please can you tell me.

Comment: This should be added to each page but since this is WP, it should be in header.php but if you are not comfortable with php (because you need to generate values based on which page this is) it might be a better option to find a plugin that will add meta fields for each page and post to add these values automatically. Just search for opengraph plugin. Maybe this can be done with yoast seo plugin too, not sure though.

Comment: Hi Nick thanks for giving this suggestion. basically i have been installed yoast seo plugin. but that plugin work only for facebook. and have one more plugin its a "META TAG" do you have any idea about that plugin. please can you tell me how we can set.

Comment: Hi Ravi. Opengraph tags are used by facebook as well as linkedin and other social networks to fetch meta data about the page. So if you will have correct tags added to a page, they will work for linkekdin as well. @RincewindAssoc posted the answer that has exact tags that you need to have on your page. Check your page source in the browser to see if these tags are added to the <head> section when testing any plugin you will use.

Comment: Hello Everyone......

Please can you tell me..
i want any software related to Simple student management system.
but i want all that Features.

Can store paperwork
We can hold student information
Group into class groups
Teacher to have access and make comment.
Can send group emails.
Possibby group chat

Can use on i phone as well for attendance....

Answer (score 0):

For an image to be displayed when sharing you need to set the meta tags in the head of the page for it. 
what you set as 'og:image' is the image that will be displayed.
Make sure you have these set up:

```
<meta property='og:title' content='Title of the article"/>
<meta property='og:image' content='//media.example.com/ 1234567.jpg"/>
<meta property='og:description' content='Description that will show in the preview"/>
<meta property='og:url' content='//www.example.com/URL of the article" />
```

[source](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi thank you really it's very help full but  where i'll put that code on wordpress website........ and which page...............